# Python email script fails unless smtplib is first called in interactive window

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a script that sends an email via a mail server.  The script only works when I call `import smtplib` first in the interactive window.  Otherwise, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named MIMEMultipart

Can someone help me understand the underlying reason behind this behavior?

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

# Fill in the necessary blanks here
gmail_user = "<your user name>"
gmail_pwd = "<your password>"

def mail(to, subject, text):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    mailServer =smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()

mail("<recipient's email>",
     "Hello from python!",
     "This is an email sent with python")
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: I'm running the script using Pythonwin directly from the script window.

Comment: I don't know what a script window is, but the normal way to run a script is by running it with the python interpreter: `python scriptname.py` on a command line. Try that.

Comment: No luck running the script via IDLE either, except if I run "import smtplib" on the command line first.

Comment: Which is also not the command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could it be that either your script is named "email.py" or that you have an "email.py" (or "email.pyc" etc) file in your current directory ?

Comment: Thanks Bruno!  Lesson learned.  I named the script email.py.  After renaming the script something other than a module name it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get such a result (*Python 2.7.6*):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  2 2013, 20:02:46) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
>>>
```